# Generic Table Name Executed in a Loop

Tags: sql-server

I have a db with many companies in it. What I am trying to is, I want to insert data to each company's table's from a different db which also has the same companies and tables in it. I created a loop using a table that contains the company names and in that loop I would like to insert from one db to another by generating the table name in loop. I created a loop which gives me the company names in it but I couldn't find the way to use results to generate the object name. My query is like;

```
declare @Rowcount int 
select @Rowcount=count(*) from [DB_1].[dbo].[Companies];

while( @Rowcount>0)
begin 

//Begin Insert Data From DB_1 to DB_2 with sames company names
INSERT INTO [DB_1].[dbo].[**[DB_1].[dbo].[Companies].[CompanyName]**$SomeTable]           
       ([Field_1],
        [Field_2])
SELECT
        [Field_1],
        [Field_2]
FROM [DB_2].[dbo].[**[DB_1].[dbo].[Companies].[CompanyName]**$SomeTable]
//End Insert Data From DB_1 to DB_2 with sames company names

SELECT @Rowcount=@Rowcount-1;  
SELECT Name FROM [DB_1].[dbo].[Companies] order by Name desc OFFSET @Rowcount ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
end
```

So basically I couldnt find a way to generate [DB_1].[dbo].[Companies].[CompanyName] as a variable to use in insert query.

I will be more than happy if you can show me how to generate the company name in the loop and use it inside the insert query.

Thanks and Regards,
Ararat

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?!

Comment: I'd suggest SQL Server, considering the OP has 3 part naming, with (what I assume is) a schema called `dbo`.

Comment: Although, honestly, I have no idea what this is meant to represent: `[DB_1].[dbo].[**[DB_1].[dbo].[Companies].[CompanyName]**$SomeTable]`. Is that a naming convention inside a naming convention???  If so, right brackets (`]`) need to be escaped.

Comment: **[DB_1].[dbo].[Companies].[CompanyName]** part is just to emphasize where I want to generate the company name. I want to use the result of [DB_1].[dbo].[Companies].[CompanyName] in between ** - **

Comment: It is SQL Server, sorry for the MySQL tag

Comment: you need to use dynamic SQL to be able to pass the object names dynamically. There is no other way

Comment: Make a cursor with a concat of dbname and tablename. Loop over these and create a dynamic sql string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable which will be contain a table name:
`declare @table_name nvarchar(200)`

Declare a variable which will contain executing query:
`declare @query nvarchar(2000)`

In the loop resolve table_name variable. For can suggest two instances:

1. `set @table_name = "some pattern" + sysdatetime()`
2. `set @table_name = "some pattern" + @Rowcount`

Both ways are good because of its guarantee a unique name for the table.

After that, resolve the @query variable and will execute the query:

```
...
@query = "INSERT INTO " + @table_name +       " ([Field_1],
        [Field_2])
SELECT
        [Field_1],
        [Field_2]
FROM [DB_2].[dbo].[**[DB_1].[dbo].[Companies].[CompanyName]**$SomeTable]
//End Insert Data From DB_1 to DB_2 with sames company names"

exec sp_executesql @query
...
```

**FYI**

I wanted to pay your attention to the variable named `rowcount` able to make a confusion. In MS SQL  exists a system variable `@@rowcount` which returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. 
For more information check documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017